# Number of companies with a given status per month starting on a custom day and time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following PostgreSQL table:

```sql
create table companies (
        id               bigserial primary key,
        created_at       timestamp(6),  
        name             varchar(200),   
        status           varchar(200)
);
```

I would like to split the result by month and to pass the months by param.
How I can get the following result using SQL query:

| created_at | Active | Blocked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-8-07 18:06:56.000000 | 54 | 32 |
| 2023-5-07 18:06:56.000000 | 51 | 13 |
| 2023-12-07 18:06:56.000000 | 35 | 35 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) in combination with an aggregate [`filter`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clause: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/B4BtOeQh)

```sql
select date_trunc('month',created_at-'6d 18:06:56'::interval)
                                    +'6d 18:06:56'::interval as created_at,
       count(*)filter(where status='Active') as "Active",
       count(*)filter(where status='Blocked') as "Blocked"
from companies
group by 1 order by 1;
```

It subtracts the custom month start, aligns the result to the beginning of the month, restores the start point. If `created_at` was on or after that custom start point, it'll stay in its month. Otherwise it'll be assigned to the previous one.

Based on this:

| id | created_at | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-07 18:06:55.9 | Right before custom October start | Active |
| 2 | 2023-10-07 18:06:56.01 | Right after custom October start | Blocked |
| 3 | 2022-11-03 17:53:38.894278 | a5b4172 | Blocked |
| 4 | 2022-10-03 14:52:14.827078 | 2bfc05d9-25f4- | Active |

It returns this:

| created_at | Active | Blocked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-07 18:06:56 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-10-07 18:06:56 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-09-07 18:06:56 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-10-07 18:06:56 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: it's not clear why do you add `'2023-8-07 18:06:56.000000'` This is a regex?

Comment: It's not, it's there only to align it to your desired output but after re-reading your question I'm beginning to suspect you mean custom ranges, as in months that begin on that specific date and time. If that's the case, do you want months that span until the same day and time the next month, or exactly 28/30/31 days?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I added an edit assuming you mean assignment to months beginning on a custom day and time. This still requires some additional handling for whenever someone specifies their custom month periods start after day 28, in which case February never catches anything, or 31st, when it'll be the case every other month.

Comment: How I can send as a param let's say 7 in order to get last 7 months?

Comment: Add a `where now()-'7 months'::interval < created_at`

Comment: I have a question. I tried to implement the query but I get error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77919510/add-placeholder-in-sql-query/77919750?noredirect=1#comment137369295_77919750 Is it possible to edit the query in some way in order to avoid the characters?

Comment: @PeterPenzov It sure is. I've posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77920425/5298879) with colons removed completely from the statement. Thanks for posting that separately.

Answer (score 1):

so you want to group by month and count on each month how many are active and how many are blocked?

you can do this with

```
SELECT 
DATEPART(month, created_at) AS Monthly,
count(case when status = 'Active' then 1 else null end) as Active,
count(case when status = 'Blocked' then 1 else null end) as Blocked,
FROM companies
GROUP BY DATEPART(month, created_at)
```

if you want to group it based on year-month:

```
SELECT 
FORMAT(created_at, 'yyyy_MM') AS year_month,
count(case when status = 'Active' then 1 else null end) as Active,
count(case when status = 'Blocked' then 1 else null end) as Blocked,
FROM companies
GROUP BY FORMAT(created_at, 'yyyy_MM')
```

hope this helps

Comment: I get error: `[42883] ERROR: function format(timestamp without time zone, unknown) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 9`

Comment: you can cast it first
'to_date(cast(createddate as TEXT),'YYYY-MM-DD') '