# Placeholder in PostgreSQL query with double colon :: cast

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this SQL query:

```sql
select date_trunc('month',created_at-'6d 18:06:56'::interval)
                                    +'6d 18:06:56'::interval as created_at,
       count(*)filter(where status='ACTIVE') as active,
       count(*)filter(where status='BLOCKED') as blocked
from companies
where now()-'12 months'::interval < created_at
group by 1 order by 1;
```

I tried to use it into Spring Data JPA repository like this:

```java
@Query(value = """
            select date_trunc('month',created_at-'6d 18:06:56'::interval)
                                   +'6d 18:06:56'::interval as created_at,
                                   count(*)filter(where status='ACTIVE') as active,
                                   count(*)filter(where status='BLOCKED') as blocked
                            from companies
                            where now()- :months + ' months'::interval < created_at
                            group by 1 order by 1"""
            , nativeQuery = true)
    List<Result> companiesMonths(@Param("months") Integer months);
```

But I get error:

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
```

What is the proper way to implement this?

Comment: Use the standard syntax CAST(), that makes the query also easier to understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping the colon character ':' in JPA queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169582/escaping-the-colon-character-in-jpa-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Spring doesn't like the colons, you can get rid of them entirely: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wy7_MX-a)

```sql
select date_trunc('month',created_at-interval '6d 18h06m56s')
                                    +interval '6d 18h06m56s' as created_at,
       count(*)filter(where status='Active') as "Active",
       count(*)filter(where status='Blocked') as "Blocked"
from companies
where now() - :months * interval '1 month' < created_at
group by 1 order by 1;
```

Even the literal can use `h`, `m` and `s` instead of colon-separated time format. That's all equivalent [cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) syntax in PostgreSQL:

- `cast('6d 18h06m56s' as interval)`
- `'6d 18h06m56s'::interval`
- `interval '6d 18h06m56s'`